# Add text to div that increments alone with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I'm trying to do the same thing as on this site http://www.internetlivestats.com/one-second/

As you can see there is a number on increment to infinity going up x times per second.

I'm stuck, if someone could help me out that'd be great.
This is what I've come up with so far (I'm aware it doesn't work for now)

index.html

```
<div class="twitter"></div>
<div class="instagram"></div>
```

script.js

```
var total = 0;
var twitterMultiplier = 7135;
var instagramMultiplier = 487;

var update = function() {
  document.getElementByClassName("twitter").innerHTML = "Tweets per second: " + Math.round(total + 7135);
  document.getElementByClassName("instagram").innerHTML = "Images per second: " + Math.round(total + 487);
}
window.setInterval(function(){
  update();
}, 100);
```

Comment: Try incrementing `total`. `total += 1` or something similar. Also, it doesn't look like you're using those multipliers to multiply.

Comment: Another thing to notice: `setInterval` called with a second argument of `100` will fire **10 times by second**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't perform any mutation of the local variables, so the values you see are always going to be 7135 and 487. You also have some syntax errors.

Here's how I might approach this a little differently.

```js
    // Maintain and simple map of the settings you need
    var timeMap = {
      'twitter': {
        total: 0,
        rate: 7135,
        label: 'Tweets per second: '
      },
      'instagram': {
        total: 0,
        rate: 487,
        label: 'Images per second: '
      }
    };

    // The update function loops over the map, updates each total by
    // the rate value, and uses the map key and label to find the element 
    // by ID in the DOM and builds the output string
    var update = function() {
      for (var site in timeMap) {
        timeMap[site].total += timeMap[site].rate;
        document.getElementById(site).innerHTML = timeMap[site].label + timeMap[site].total.toString();
      }
    };

    // runs every 1000 milliseconds
    window.setInterval(update, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="twitter"></div>
<div id="instagram"></div>
```

This approach will let you add more and more sites with ease -- no need to ever change the `update()` function.

Comment: Although other answers did exactly what I was looking for I'm accepting this one as it's the most intuitive and great as I need to add lot's more, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementByClassName`. There is a `getElementsByClassName`.

There can be multiple elements on the page with the same class name. As such the method returns multiple elements.

Since you are trying to retrieve specific individual elements, you should use id rather than class.

```
<div id="twitter">...</div>

document.getElementById('twitter')...
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName() doesn't return an array, but a htmlCollection.

Comment: @mmm - fair enough. Not much of a difference though. The console even logs it in array brackets [..., ...].

Comment: The console may log it equally, but you'll notice the difference once you try to use Array.prototype methods (like .forEach(), .map(), ...) on it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just getting the values returning and not incrementing? If so, it's because total isn't being increased. I'm guessing that you were going for something like this:

```
var twitterTotal = 0;
var instagramTotal = 0;
var twitterMultiplier = 7135;
var instagramMultiplier = 487;

var update = function() {
    twitterTotal += twitterMultiplier;
  instagramTotal += instagramMultiplier;
  document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML = "Tweets per second: " + Math.round(twitterTotal);
  document.getElementById("instagram").innerHTML = "Images per second: " + Math.round(instagramTotal);
}
window.setInterval(function(){
  update();
}, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4f5h07w2/

Comment: @kreitzo , As Cory mentions, this will increment every 1/10th of a second, so just tweak the 100 in the setInterval function to whatever amount you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you are using `document.getElementByClassName` this function doesn't exist, it should be: `document.getElementsByClassName`. However when you are updating a specific element I would suggest you use `document.getElementById` instead.

your html then becomes:

```
<div id="twitter"></div>
<div id="instagram"></div>
```

secondly, you are not incrementing the total, so your value will remain static:

```
var total = 0;
var twitterMultiplier = 7135;
var instagramMultiplier = 487;

var update = function() {
  total++; //incrementing total every interval
  document.getElementById("twitter").innerHTML = "Tweets per second: " + Math.round(total * 7135); //multiply with total here.
  document.getElementById("instagram").innerHTML = "Images per second: " + Math.round(total * 487); //multiply with total here.
}

window.setInterval(function(){
  update();
}, 100);
```

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o6rmx1ds/

Answer (score -1):

be sure to increment total.
you can use

- total++ (add one to it)
- total += 1
- total = total + 1

it's your choice!

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue that `document.getElementByClassName` does not exist as a function.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use "getElementsByClassName" (note the s in Elements) and then reference the first item in the array.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("twitter")[0].innerHTML = "Tweets per second: " + Math.round(total + 7135);
document.getElementsByClassName("instagram")[0].innerHTML = "Images per second: " + Math.round(total + 487);
```

Comment: This will not increment the values as total will always be 0